# twilio - stop flow when call end

Tags: twilio, twilio-php

I have set up a twilio number. When a call comes in, the caller is welcomed with a welcome message, and then the call is forwarded to my cell phone. If the call is not answered, the call goes to a voice mail message, telling the caller to leave a message, and the the call goes to the voice mail. All that works just fine.
But if the call is answered, and I hang up, the flow will not stop. It goes on to the voice mail message. Now my question is:

How do I stop the flow, when the call ends?

This is my code:

```
<?php
header('content-type: text/xml');
echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n";
?>
<Response>
<Play>http://example.com/telephone/sounds/welcome-message.mp3</Play>
<Dial record="true" timeout="25">
<Number url="http://example.com/telephone/wisper.php">
+4581732211
</Number>
</Dial>
<Play>http://example.com/telephone/sounds/no-answer.mp3</Play>
<Record transcribe="true" transcribeCallback="http://twimlets.com/voicemail?Email=mail@mydomain.com"/>
</Response>
```

Comment: Did my answer solved your issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, both Dial and Record is happening in the same TwiML file. So conditional execution is not possible.

To solve this,
 1. Move the recording part to another file. (Say `recording.php`)
 2. Then specify the url of the new file (`recording.php`) as action during Dial. When the dial is completed, twilio will make a request to this URL, and the execution will continue with the TwiML received from this URL.
 3. Check the value request parameter `DialCallStatus` in `recording.php`. If the dialed call is answered, the value will be `completed` or `answered` (In case of conference). Route the call accordingly in `recording.php`

**dial.php**

```
<?php
header('content-type: text/xml');
echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n";
?>
<Response>
    <Play>http://example.com/telephone/sounds/welcome-message.mp3</Play>
    <Dial record="true" timeout="25" action="http://example.com/telephone/recording.php">
        <Number url="http://example.com/telephone/wisper.php">
            +4581732211
        </Number>       
    </Dial>
</Response>
```

**recording.php**

```
<?php
header('content-type: text/xml');
echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n";
$dial_call_status = $_REQUEST['DialCallStatus'];
if($dial_call_status == "completed" || $dial_call_status == "answered"){
?>
    <Response>
        <Hangup/>
    </Response>
<?php
}else{
?>
    <Response>
            <Play>http://example.com/telephone/sounds/no-answer.mp3</Play>
            <Record transcribe="true" transcribeCallback="http://twimlets.com/voicemail?Email=mail@mydomain.com"/>
    </Response>
<?php
}
?>
```